# How to make a data structure which can hold 100 most recent record_values basis on timestamp?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, dictionary

I am getting data for a particular user id from 14 tables as shown below. As part of data, I am extracting `user_id`, `record_name` and `record_value` and then I get `timestamp` from `record_name` (by splitting on it) and then populate my TreeMap with key as `timestamp` and value as `record_value`.

After that I am extracting 100 most recent `record_value` from `valueTimestampMap` and then populating it in my `recordValueHolder` LinkedList.

In my case 100 most recent means by looking at the timestamp not the way they are coming.

Below is my code -

```
public List<String> getData(String userId) {

    List<String> recordValueHolder = new LinkedList<String>();
    Map<Long, String> valueTimestampMap = new TreeMap<Long, String>(Collections.reverseOrder());

    for (int tableNumber = 0; tableNumber < 14; tableNumber++) {

        String sql = "select * from table_" + tableNumber + " where user_id='" + userId + "';";

        SimpleStatement query = new SimpleStatement(sql);
        query.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM);
        ResultSet res = session.execute(query);

        Iterator<Row> rows = res.iterator();
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            Row r = rows.next();

            String user_id = r.getString("user_id"); // get user id
            String record_name = r.getString("record_name"); // get record name
            String record_value = r.getString("record_value"); // get record value

            long timestamp = Long.parseLong(record_name.split("\\.")[1]);

            // populate my tree map
            valueTimestampMap.put(timestamp, record_value);
        }
    }

    // now extract 100 most recent record_value since
    // valueTimestampMap is already sorted basis on key in
    // descending order
    for (Map.Entry<Long, String> entry : valueTimestampMap.entrySet()) {
        if (recordValueHolder.size() > 99)
            break;
        recordValueHolder.add(entry.getValue());
    }       

    return recordValueHolder;
}
```

I am sorting TreeMap in descending order of the keys by using `Collections.reverseOrder()` so that I have most recent timestamps at the top and then I can simply extract 100 most recent `record_value` from it and that's what my above code does.

**Problem Statement:-**

I have 100 most recent `record_value` in recordValueHolder List. Now I also need to find out which `tableNumber` each `record_value` out of 100 came from and what was the `record_name` for that `record_value` as well?

So I was thinking to make a data structure something like below which can hold 100 most recent `record_value` along with their tableNumber, record_name and timestamp as well.

```
public class RecordValueTimestampTableHolder {

    private long timestamp;
    private String recordName;
    private String recordValue;
    private Integer tableNumber;

    // setters and getters

}
```

So the size of `List<RecordValueTimestampTableHolder>` should be 100. Is this possible to do with my current setup? I am not able to understand how to make this work?

Now my return data type of `getData` method will change and instead of returning `List<String>`, now it will return `List<RecordValueTimestampTableHolder>` which will have 100 most recent record_values along with other values as well.

Comment: i am little bit confused. but if `timestamp` is what you base on, then a `TreeMap` is a right choice. each time you can pop out the one with least `timestamp`. but if when your system is running, `timestamp` can be interpreted as the time the data comes, then a simple 100-long array is enough, and it's faster than `TreeMap` way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `TreeMap<Long, String>`, use `TreeMap<Long, RecordValueTimestampTableHolder>`

Instead of using

```
        valueTimestampMap.put(timestamp, record_value);
```

use:

```
        valueTimestampMap.put(timestamp, new RecordValueTimestampTableHolder(timestamp, record_name, record_value, tableNumber));
```

Of course, this means you will have to add a constructor to `RecordValueTimestampTableHolder` that accepts the four parameters and assigns them to the internal fields.

As you said `recordValueHolder` will have to be defined as a `List<RecordValueTimestampTableHolder>` and this will also have to be the return type from this method.

Filling it will be exactly like you fill it now. Though personally I'd use `valueTimestampMap.values()` to iterate.

```
int i = 0;
for (RecordValueTimestampTableHolder item : valueTimestampMap.values()) {
    recordValueHolder.add(item);
    if (++i == 100)
        break;
}
```